# Strapi Content Manager 500 Internal Server Error when updating relation field

Tags: strapi

I am having an issue that is only seemingly occurring on the live production website (it does not occur on a staging website or locally) when attempting to update a relation field, I get the following error during the PUT request

```
{
    "data": null,
    "error": {
        "status": 500,
        "name": "InternalServerError",
        "message": "Internal Server Error"
    }
}
```

This issue has just occurred recently and I'm not actually sure where to look to resolve this issue?

This is the schema of the content type `article` which holds the related field with the issue `category`

```
{
  "kind": "collectionType",
  "collectionName": "articles",
  "info": {
    "singularName": "article",
    "pluralName": "articles",
    "displayName": "Articles",
    "description": ""
  },
  "options": {
    "draftAndPublish": true
  },
  "pluginOptions": {},
  "attributes": {
    "Title": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "Slug": {
      "type": "uid",
      "targetField": "Title",
      "required": true
    },
    "SEO": {
      "type": "component",
      "repeatable": false,
      "component": "seo.seo",
      "required": true
    },
    "Excerpt": {
      "type": "text",
      "maxLength": 240
    },
    "categories": {
      "type": "relation",
      "relation": "oneToMany",
      "target": "api::category.category"
    },
    "Content": {
      "type": "richtext",
      "required": true
    },
    "Poster": {
      "type": "media",
      "multiple": false,
      "required": false,
      "allowedTypes": ["images", "files", "videos", "audios"]
    },
    "Gallery": {
      "type": "media",
      "multiple": true,
      "required": false,
      "allowedTypes": ["images", "files", "videos", "audios"]
    }
  }
}
```

and this is the category schema

```
{
  "kind": "collectionType",
  "collectionName": "categories",
  "info": {
    "singularName": "category",
    "pluralName": "categories",
    "displayName": "Category",
    "description": ""
  },
  "options": {
    "draftAndPublish": true
  },
  "pluginOptions": {},
  "attributes": {
    "Name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

in the `PUT` request this is the `categories` property and it's value in the body of the request

```
{
    "disconnect": [],
    "connect": [
        {
            "id": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

The initial creation of the content type `article` is fine, you can select the categories, it's only once you attempt to update the `categories` does the error arise.

This is the body on the `POST` for creating an article

```
{
    "SEO": {
        "PageTitle": ""
    },
    "categories": {
        "disconnect": [],
        "connect": [
            {
                "id": 3
            }
        ]
    },
    "Slug": "article-1",
    "Content": ""
}
```

Then when attempting to immediately update the article by adding a new category, this is the `PUT` body

```
{
    "id": 40,
    "Title": null,
    "Content": "",
    "createdAt": "2023-07-03T09:47:41.052Z",
    "updatedAt": "2023-07-03T09:47:41.052Z",
    "publishedAt": null,
    "Slug": "article-1",
    "Excerpt": null,
    "SEO": {
        "id": 30,
        "PageTitle": "",
        "MetaDescription": null
    },
    "categories": {
        "disconnect": [],
        "connect": [
            {
                "id": 2
            }
        ]
    },
    "Poster": null,
    "Gallery": null,
    "createdBy": 1,
    "updatedBy": 1
}
```

Which returns the 500 error.

I've checked the ADMINISTRATION PANEL Roles & USERS & PERMISSIONS PLUGIN Roles on both the dev site where there is no issue and the live site and they seem to match up.

on the server logs, I can see this error message

```
Error: ER_GTID_UNSAFE_CREATE_DROP_TEMPORARY_TABLE_IN_TRANSACTION: Statement violates GTID consistency: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE and DROP TEMPORARY TABLE can only be executed outside transactional context.  These statements are also not allowed in a function or trigger because functions and triggers are also considered to be multi-statement transactions.
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/opt/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/opt/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:79:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/opt/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/opt/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (/opt/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (/opt/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/opt/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/opt/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was previously on strapi version 4.5.3 and updated to 4.10.7 and the problem no longer persists.